# How can i update a value in mysql database with php when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: php

In database i am updating the height of an image and after the checkbox is checked i want to see the image with that height.Any idea what should i be using to achieve this ? An example would be appreciated.

Comment: An example would also be appreciated to explain what you're trying to do. At the moment I have no idea what you're having trouble with or what this checkbox is supposed to achieve.

Comment: Please share some code where you're facing trouble or define a little bit more what is the purpose of that checkbox you mentioned.

Comment: I just want a checkbox to change height of image in database and to be able to see the mage straight away after checkbox is checked. I can show the image i have taken care of that but i don't have any idea what to use to change height this is what i am asking. Maybe ajax or a php function this is where i am not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, what you need to do is implement ajax for async call to database for updating image's height in database and vanilla JavaScript (or jQuery) to resize image after the request is successful.

**For Example:**

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="your_checkbox" value="50" onclick="changeHeight(this);">

<img src="image/url/here.jpg" alt="foo" class="your-class" id="img">
```

**JavaScript**

```
let changeHeight = checkbox => {
    if(checkbox.checked){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'your/path/to/updating/file.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {img_height: checkbox.value}
            success: res => {
                $('#img').css({height: checkbox.value+'px'});
            },
            error: err => {
                console.error(err);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**PHP**

```
$height = $_POST['img_height'];

// query to update height in the database...
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for

Comment: @Ben Glad to be of any help. If this answer solved your problem, kindly mark it as solved. Thanks!